# How to apply workbook event on new workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

I intend to:

- move to last activated sheet if the active sheet is the first sheet in the workbook.
- move to the first sheet in the workbook otherwise.

Code in `thisworkbook` module in addin (`.xlam`):

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetdeActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Set LstSht = Sh
End Sub
```

Code in a general module in addin (`.xlam`):

```vb
Global LstSht As Worksheet

Sub GoToLast()
    LstSht.Activate
End Sub

Private Sub Sht_tab()
    If ActiveSheet.Index = 1 Then
        Call GoToLast
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Index <> 1 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

When I move to any other sheet in workbook, the `sheetdeactivate` event is not triggered, so `LstSht` object is not defined.

The `sheetdeactivate` event works in a specific workbook.

I want to assign a shortcut to use it in other workbooks.

Comment: If you want to capture events across all open workbooks then you need to capture events at the Application level - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-application-level-event-handler

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for the advice. I googled to use application level events procedure with Class module, it's working well.

Comment: For someone who might have some questions like mine, i hope it would be helpful: https://geekexcel.com/how-to-create-application-level-events-in-excel-vba/